# Autocomplete with arrray?

Tags: angular

I have this autocomplete component:

```
 <z-autocomplete class="z-autocomplete" *ngIf="!ipaddress.rinvapnId" (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)" [suggestion]="results"  (searchEvent)="search($event)" [fieldname]="'addressname'" ></z-autocomplete>
```

In ts i have this:

```
search(e){

    console.log(this.IPresults.includes(a=>a.apn==e.query),'aaa');
}
```

How to return all data from array that starts with that string ? something LIKE method in sql. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `filter` function :

```
return this.IPresults.filter(result => result.startsWith(e.query) );
```

> Above snippet is just answer of `How to return all data from array
>   that starts with that string ?` , you can do that many ways (e.g.
>   regex) .
>
> Its all about how you implements the logic.